# Kubernetes pod readiness probe failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubeflow

I have a kubernetes cluster running with minikube in my local. I am trying to train a model with KubeFlow's TFJob operator which implements TensorFlow's distributed training strategies.

The YAML for the TFJob looks like this

```
apiVersion: kubeflow.org/v1
kind: TFJob
metadata:
  name: tf-job-cifar
  namespace: kubeflow
spec:
  tfReplicaSpecs:
    Worker:
      replicas: 2
      restartPolicy: Never
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: tensorflow
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: tensorflow
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              image: tf-dist-cifar10:1.0
              livenessProbe:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - cat
                    - /tmp/healthy
                initialDelaySeconds: 10
                periodSeconds: 5
              readinessProbe:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - cat
                    - /tmp/healthy
                initialDelaySeconds: 10
                periodSeconds: 5
```

When I deploy this YAML using `kubectl create -f <file-name>.yaml`. The pods thus created for the job fails with error:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.31:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 172.17.0.31:15021: connect: connection refused
```

The error after few minutes changes to:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.31:15021/healthz/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Where could possibly the error be?

Comment: It seems that you try to add liveness command from this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command But did you check that `/tmp/healthy` folder is exist in the pod? In example you can see that this folder is creating with `- touch /tmp/healthy;` command.